preg_replace different replacement for each match
I'm trying to preg_replace() a string with a different replacement for each found match. Below is an example string and the pattern to look for:
$string = "111111Z not-a-match 000000Z not-a-match 000000Z";
$pattern = "/\d{6}Z/";

I want to be able to replace the matches based on the order they were found. For example, replace the first match ('111111Z') with '123456Z'. Meaning my desired value would be something like:
$newString = "123456Z not-a-match 654321Z not-a-match 012345Z"

It is important to note that the replacements will also match the expression.
What is the best way to get from $string to $newString?
I've been looking into setting a $matches variable in either a preg_match_all() or a preg_replace_callback(), and then loop through each match, but I'm struggling to get back around to the full original string with the matches replaced.

Are FIRST, SECOND and THIRD static values?

If so, then this will work.
echo preg_replace([$pattern,$pattern,$pattern],['FIRST','SECOND','THIRD'], $string);

it will be based on the index of the match, but it's not just the index. so these are time strings (DAYHOURMINUTEZ), and basically the first match is going to be a set time, the second match, and hour earlier, third match 2 hours earlier, and so on. The example replacement strings are just to illustrate the replacement is different for each match, but it's not just replace the first match with "1". Let me look into that method and get back. the one thing about that solution, is that the number of matches isn't always going to be 3, I might be able to account for that somehow but idk. STBY...

Technically the source of replacement could be anything, you could also pass a function or object to do sophisticated stuff to determine a new value... as long as you return a string from the callback, it'll be fine I guess.

ok. this works except for one thing, in the preg_replace() the 4th parameter must be sent as 1 to limit the replacements made each time. because we're always using the same pattern, and it will match every occurence and try to replace all of them on the first replacement string otherwise. so if we do preg_replace([$pattern,$pattern,$pattern],['FIRST','SECOND','THIRD'], $string) we get 'FIRST other FIRST other FIRST'. but if we do preg_replace([$pattern,$pattern,$pattern],['FIRST','SECOND','THIRD'], $string, 1), we get 'FIRST other SECOND other THIRD'. and I can set those arrays up before hand!

I also realized i left out an important detail. "FIRST" "SECOND" and "THIRD" were example replacements. the actually replacements will match the regex as well. so the above method will therefore not work because it will keep replacing ones that have already been handled. modifying the question now...

One way is preg_replace_callback(), using an extra array with the replacements:
$string = "111111Z not-a-match 000000Z not-a-match 000000Z";
$pattern = "/\d{6}Z/";

$newString = "FIRST not-a-match SECOND not-a-match THIRD";
$returns = [
  'FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD'    
];

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function(array $matches) use(&$returns) {
    return array_shift($returns);
}, $string);

var_dump($newString, $result);

Output
string(42) "FIRST not-a-match SECOND not-a-match THIRD"
string(42) "FIRST not-a-match SECOND not-a-match THIRD"


This is the best way to do this and account for replacements that also match the expression

Use preg_replace() with the replacement limit optional argument, so it only replaces each match once before going to the next element of the pattern and replacement arrays.
$newString = preg_replace([$pattern, $pattern, $pattern], ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD'], $string, 1);


You can try this
    // Define a callback function for replacement
function replaceCallback($matches) {
    static $count = 0;
    $replacements = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD'];
    
    // Replace each match with the corresponding word
    if ($count < count($replacements)) {
        return $replacements[$count++];
    }
    
    // Return the original match if there are no more replacements
    return $matches[0];
}

 $string = "111111Z not-a-match 000000Z not-a-match 000000Z";
    $newString = preg_replace_callback('/\d+Z/', 'replaceCallback', $string);
    dd($newString);

OUTPUT
"FIRST not-a-match SECOND not-a-match THIRD"


To solve this, you can use preg_replace_callback() in PHP, which allows you to define a custom function to handle each match. This custom function will keep track of the match order and replace each match with the corresponding value ('FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD', etc.).
<?php
$string = "111111Z not-a-match 000000Z not-a-match 000000Z";
$pattern = "/\d{6}Z/";

$replacements = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD'];
$index = 0;

$newString = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use (&$index, $replacements) {
    return $replacements[$index++];
}, $string);

echo $newString;
?>

